# RecordLinkage Package and RLBigDataLinkage-Class Objects

Tags: r

I am attempting to use R package RecordLinkage, and am using [two](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Sariyar+Borg.pdf) [articles](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/vignettes/BigData.pdf) by the package authors as usage guides, in addition to the package [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/RecordLinkage.pdf).

I am using 2 large datasets (100k+ rows), which I hope to link, and so I am using those elements of the package which are built around S4 class `RLBigDataLinkage`.

I begin by running the following lines in R:

```
>library('RecordLinkage')
>data1 <- as.data.frame(#source)
>data2 <- as.data.frame(#source)
>rpairs <- RLBigDataLinkage(data1, data2, strcmp = 2:8, exclude = 9:10)
```

This works fine (though it takes some time), and writes the necessary .ff files to deal with the large data sets.

If I then try:

```
>rpairs <- epiWeights(rpairs)
```

Or:

```
>rpairs <- epiWeights(rpairs, e = 0.01, f = getFrequencies(rpairs))
```

Then when I run:

```
>summary(rpairs)
```

I get the error message:

```
Error in dbGetQuery(object@con, "select count(*) from data1") : 
    error in evaluating the argument 'conn' in selecting a method for function 'dbGetQuery': Error: no slot of name "con" for this object of class "RLBigDataLinkage"
```

If, on the other hand, I run:

```
>result <- epiClassify(rpairs, 0.5)
>getTable(result)
```

I get the error message:

```
Error in table.ff(object@data@pairs$is_match, object@prediction, useNA = "ifany") : 
     Only vmodes integer currently allowed - are you sure ... contains only factors or integers?
```

I'm clearly missing something about how these objects need to be handled.  Does anyone have any experience with this package that sees my error?  Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 0):

when the type of 'rpairs' is 'RLBigDataLinkage' use `print(rpairs)` ,you will get the summary of rpairs.